# How can I get iStat Menus or activity monitor to display download speed after switching to realtek driver?

Tags: macos, network, ethernet, driver

I decided to buy a usb 3 to ethernet adapter for my macbook air for faster downloads, but was getting system slowdowns by a process called AppleUserECM, explained in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/gukh9c/fyi_usbc_hubs_with_ethernet_might_cause_high_cpu/

I installed the latest realtek driver and it is better now, and faster, but for some reason download speeds do not register at all in iStat Menus or in activity monitor, while upload does register. It must be some bug or something.

Any ideas? Or an idea to get a workaround menu bar notification that shows download speed? Individual programs can show it, as well from online download tests. I didn't think it was useful information, but I miss being able to see how fast files were being downloaded.

Comment: Have you written to the developer [Bjango](https://bjango.com/contact/) for help about this?

Comment: no, I actually had to uninstall the realtek driver because although it was better it was cutting out suddenly, so now I'm back with appleuserecm and kernel_task beating up my cpu, but it wasn't meant to be I don't think.